# How to set fx:value using resource bundle?

Tags: java, internationalization, javafx-2, fxml

In java fx it is possible to use i18n labels for components using the `%key` notation.

For example -

```
<Label layoutX="151.0" layoutY="14.0" text="%windowTitle">
   <font>
     <Font size="22.0" />
   </font>
</Label>
```

Is it possible to use i18n for component values?

The following code does not work -

```
<ChoiceBox layoutX="140.0" layoutY="67.0" prefWidth="164.0">
   <items>
     <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
       <String fx:value="%listValue1" />
       <String fx:value="%listValue2" />
       <String fx:value="%listValue3" />
       <String fx:value="%listValue4" />
     </FXCollections>
   </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK FXML doesn't support resource ids in meta-tags like `fx:value`. See http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-3699 for example.

You may want to file an enhancement request for that at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com