# How can I populate a javafx ChoiceBox with strings from a resourcebundle in an fxml document

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX 8 application and in a ComboBox (I actually used the equivalent JavaFX controls from the [JFoenix JavaFX Material Design Library](https://www.jfoenix.com)), I want to fill its items with string values, but I want these values to come from a resource bundle which I have already created. When I make a preview of the FXML document in Scene builder, the desired changes for the ComboBox don't occur in the scene builder previewer. Below is the FXML code.

```
<JFXComboBox fx:id="languageBox" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="321.0" promptText="%select-language-text">
        <items>
           <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="%english-text" />
              <String fx:value="%french-text" />
              <String fx:value="%spanish-text" />
              <String fx:value="%german-text" />
           </FXCollections>
        </items>
     </JFXComboBox>
```

I indicated that the values should come from the resource bundle, but they did not load from the resource bundle. Below is the preview image.
Please can someone help me with this, It will be very much appreciated.

[image: preview image]

Comment: Did you give the `FXMLLoader` the appropriate `ResourceBundle`?

Comment: Yes, I did. as you can see in the other nodes the text is in German

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153446/how-to-set-fxvalue-using-resource-bundle it doesn't seem possible to use localization with `fx:value`. And it doesn't seem like they've gotten around to implementing it: [JDK-8090733](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090733)

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930701/how-can-i-populate-a-javafx-choicebox-with-strings-from-a-resourcebundle-in-an-f?noredirect=1#comment90933261_51930701) it appears that using `%` syntax with `fx:value` is not supported. There is a [feature request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090733) for this but it hasn't been implemented and might never be (issue hasn't been updated since June of 2015).

You can do what you want inside the controller class, however.

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private JFXComboBox<String> languageBox;
    @FXML private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        languageBox.getItems().addAll(
            resources.getString("english-text"),
            resources.getString("french-text"),
            resources.getString("spanish-text"),
            resources.getString("german-text")
        );
    }

}
```

The `resources` field will be injected with the `ResourceBundle` given to the `FXMLLoader`. Or you could implement the [`Initializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private JFXComboBox<String> languageBox;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        languageBox.getItems().addAll(
            resources.getString("english-text"),
            resources.getString("french-text"),
            resources.getString("spanish-text"),
            resources.getString("german-text")
        );
    }

}
```